# When is the duplication of database data okay?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

When is it okay to have duplication of data in your database?

I'm working on this application that is supposed to track the number of user downloads. From my layman's point of view I can

1. simply have a column in the user table and increment the counter every time the user downloads something, or
2. have a counter table that has two columns, one for the user and one for the downloaded file.

As I see it both options enable me to track how many downloads each user has.  However if this application sees the light of day and has tons of users then querying the database to look through the whole counter table could be quite expensive.

I guess my question is which do you all recommend?

Comment: You're tracking different information in the two cases.  If you want to be able to know *which* files the user downloaded, then obviously the first case won't help at all.

Comment: By the way, when you're dealing with a web app and databases, you need to take a lot of precautions to make sure you're not getting race conditions and losing data because it's being updated in two separate threads.  Just slapping a big lock on the whole table for the duration of the download is NOT a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no data duplication in the second option, just more data.

If you're not interested in knowing which files are downloaded, I go for the first option (takes least space). If you are, go for the second.

At some point, though, you might also be interested to see the download trend over time :) have you considered logging downloads using Google Analytics? They're probably a lot better at this game than you :)